# Angular 10 - How to Implement WebSocket without StompJS

Tags: angular, spring, websocket, stomp

what's the best way to implement WebSocket Connections with current Angular version 10?
As StompJS is an outdated library, I'm wondering if there's no modern (typescript) solution to handle websockets in Angular?

Does someone know a good example/documentation or tutorial that can help with this?

I'm using Spring Boot as Backend, there the handling of WebSockets is no problem.

Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You can use rxjs websocket (https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/webSocket/webSocket). Or Reactive-StompJS implementation: https://github.com/stomp-js/rx-stomp

Comment: Thanks! Do i have to use a Message Broker like RabbitMQ when I use this with spring boot?